# Swift 5 Saving data from json using Alamofire to an array to show it in TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I use Alamofire for JSON request to get data from the gitHub repositories, but i cant use it in TableView, here is my code:

i create class "Repos"

```
class Repos: Codable {
    var fullName: String
    var description: String
    var language: String
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case description = "description"
        case language = "language"

    }
}
```

This is ViewContoller

```
var repos = [Repos]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: idCell)
        
        fetchRepos {
            print("succsed")
        }
    }
```

then i created an extension to fetchData

```
extension ReposViewController {
    func fetchRepos(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let headers = ["Authorization": "Token ***********"]
        request("https://api.github.com/user/repos", method: .get, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { (responseJSON) in
            
            switch responseJSON.result {
            case .success:
                guard let data = responseJSON.data else { return }
                            do {
                                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                let loginRequest = try decoder.decode([Repos].self, from: data)
                                print(loginRequest.first?.fullName ?? "ed")
                                print(loginRequest[2].language)
                                print(loginRequest[3].description)
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    completed()
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                                
                            } catch let error {
                                print(error)
                            }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("вы не авторизованы! \(error)")
            }
        } .resume()
    }
}
```

Everything is good, i got data, but when i use array in tableView , i see the empty List

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return repos.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: idCell) as! TableViewCell
        
        let reposList = repos[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.titleOutlet?.text = reposList.fullName
        cell.descriptionOutlet?.text = reposList.description
        cell.languageOutlet?.text = reposList.language
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You parse the data, I see `decode([Repos].self`, you populate according to `repos`: `repos.count`, `let reposList = repos[indexPath.row]` BUT I don't see where you do `self.repo = ...`. It's always empty, never populated...

Comment: Could you help me? what should i change in my code?... Thank you

Comment: Before `self.tableView.reloadData()`, do `self.repos = loginRequest`...

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am totally new in swift, thank you!